# Automatic initialization of IIS-hosted WCF service

Tags: asp.net, iis, wcf

I have an ASP.NET web-site and a WCF service which is called from ASP. The problem is, that during the first client request the site loads aufully slow, cause some time-consuming static objects are being created inside the WCF service. Is it possible to call any service method (by doing this the wcf object will be created), when the site gets loaded in IIS? (I know there is a solution for this problem in ASP 4 and IIS 7.5, but i'd like to know what's about IIS6-7). It is something like "user emulation") Maybe i can add some event handlers in global.asax? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to use [wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) within a scheduled task in Windows to simply issue a HTTP GET to your service.  This will keep your application 'warm' and ticking over.